# how to show DatePicker antd on form

Tags: reactjs

[image]

i want to show datepicker on form and will push value to input. i tried "open" but it's not in the form and the modal opening won't close...........................................................

it my code

```
return (
    <Modal
      open={isModalOpen}
      width={410}
      footer={false}
      onCancel={visibleModal}
    >
      <Formik
        initialValues={{titleCard: ""}}
        onSubmit={() => {
          console.log("");
        }}
      >
        <Form className="form-add-new">
          <div className="title-modal">Tạo thẻ nhanh</div>
          <FormItem name="titleCard">
            <div className="title-input">
              Tiêu đề thẻ mục tiêu
              <sup className="text-orange-300">*</sup>
            </div>
            <Input className="input-add-new" name="titleCard" />
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem name="titleCard">
            <div className="title-input">
              Tên không gian làm việc
              <sup className="text-orange-300">*</sup>
            </div>
            <Input className="input-add-new" name="titleCard" />
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem name="titleCard">
            <div className="title-input">
              Vị trí của thẻ mục tiêu
              <sup className="text-orange-300">*</sup>
            </div>
            <Input className="input-add-new" name="titleCard" />
            <Checkbox.Group options={plainOptions} />
            <Space>
              <DatePicker
                picker="month"
                // style={{visibility: "hidden", width: 0}}
              />
            </Space>
          </FormItem>
          <ButtonSubmit label="Tạo thẻ mới" />
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </Modal>
  );
```

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are using multiple `FormItem` components with the same name attribute **titleCard**. Each field should have a unique name. Also use Formik's `setFieldValue` function to assign a value from the date picker to a Formik field. To close the modal use the `onSubmit` prop of Formik. Try this one ->

```
return (
  <Modal
    open={isModalOpen}
    width={410}
    footer={false}
    onCancel={visibleModal}
  >
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        titleCard: "",
        workspaceName: "",
        cardPosition: "",
        date: null
      }}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        console.log(values);
        visibleModal();
      }}
    >
      {({ setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form className="form-add-new">
          <div className="title-modal">Tạo thẻ nhanh</div>
          <FormItem name="titleCard">
            <div className="title-input">
              Tiêu đề thẻ mục tiêu
              <sup className="text-orange-300">*</sup>
            </div>
            <Input className="input-add-new" name="titleCard" />
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem name="workspaceName">
            <div className="title-input">
              Tên không gian làm việc
              <sup className="text-orange-300">*</sup>
            </div>
            <Input className="input-add-new" name="workspaceName" />
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem name="cardPosition">
            <div className="title-input">
              Vị trí của thẻ mục tiêu
              <sup className="text-orange-300">*</sup>
            </div>
            <Input className="input-add-new" name="cardPosition" />
            <Checkbox.Group options={plainOptions} />
            <Space>
              <DatePicker
                picker="month"
                onChange={(date, dateString) => setFieldValue('date', dateString)}
              />
            </Space>
          </FormItem>
          <ButtonSubmit label="Tạo thẻ mới" />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </Modal>
);
```